# in angular factory method not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know  it is a silly question. but don't know my angular factory stopped working on my page. Previously whole script was one file that time it was working later I split it into different file than it stopped working

Here's my files.

app.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('confusionApp', []);
```

controller.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('confusionApp')

        .controller('MenuController', ['$scope','menuFactory', function($scope,menuFactory) {

            $scope.tab = 1;
            $scope.filtText = '';
            $scope.showDetails = false;

            $scope.dishes=menuFactory.getDishes();

            $scope.select = function(setTab) {
                $scope.tab = setTab;

                if (setTab === 2) {
                    $scope.filtText = "appetizer";
                }
                else if (setTab === 3) {
                    $scope.filtText = "mains";
                }
                else if (setTab === 4) {
                    $scope.filtText = "dessert";
                }
                else {
                    $scope.filtText = "";
                }
            };

            $scope.isSelected = function (checkTab) {
                return ($scope.tab === checkTab);
            };

            $scope.toggleDetails = function() {
                $scope.showDetails = !$scope.showDetails;
            };
        }])

        .controller('ContactController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

            $scope.feedback = {mychannel:"", firstName:"", lastName:"", agree:false, email:"" };

            var channels = [{value:"tel", label:"Tel."}, {value:"Email",label:"Email"}];

            $scope.channels = channels;
            $scope.invalidChannelSelection = false;

        }])

        .controller('FeedbackController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

            $scope.sendFeedback = function() {

                console.log($scope.feedback);

                if ($scope.feedback.agree && ($scope.feedback.mychannel == "")) {
                    $scope.invalidChannelSelection = true;
                    console.log('incorrect');
                }
                else {
                    $scope.invalidChannelSelection = false;
                    $scope.feedback = {mychannel:"", firstName:"", lastName:"", agree:false, email:"" };
                    $scope.feedback.mychannel="";
                    $scope.feedbackForm.$setPristine();
                    console.log($scope.feedback);
                }
            };
        }])

        .controller('DishDetailController', ['$scope','menuFactory', function($scope,menuFactory) {

             $scope.dish= menuFactory.getDish(3);

        }])

        .controller('DishCommentController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

            //Step 1: Create a JavaScript object to hold the comment from the form
            var stars=[{value:"1"
                       },
                       {
                         value:"2"
                       },
                       {
                         value:"3"
                       },
                       {
                         value:"4"
                       },
                       {
                           value:"5"

                       }

                        ];

            $scope.isSelected=function(checkStar){
                console.log(checkStar==5);
                return checkStar==5;
            };

            $scope.stars=stars;

            $scope.comment={name:"",rating:"5",textComments:"",date:""};

            $scope.submitComment = function () {

                               $scope.comment.date=new Date().toISOString();

            }
        }])

;
```

service.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('confusionApp'){
    .factory('menuFactory',function(){

           var dishes=[
                         {
                          name:'Uthapizza',
                          image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                          category: 'mains',
                           label:'Hot',
                          price:'4.99',
                          description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                           comments: [
                               {
                                   rating:5,
                                   comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                                   author:"John Lemon",
                                   date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                                   author:"Paul McVites",
                                   date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:3,
                                   comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                                   author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                                   date:"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                                   author:"Ringo Starry",
                                   date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:2,
                                   comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                                   author:"25 Cent",
                                   date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               }                                                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          name:'Zucchipakoda',
                           image: 'images/zucchipakoda.png',
                          category: 'appetizer',
                           label:'',
                          price:'1.99',
                          description:'Deep fried Zucchini coated with mildly spiced Chickpea flour batter accompanied with a sweet-tangy tamarind sauce',
                          comments: [
                               {
                                   rating:5,
                                   comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                                   author:"John Lemon",
                                   date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                                   author:"Paul McVites",
                                   date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:3,
                                   comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                                   author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                                   date:"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                                   author:"Ringo Starry",
                                   date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:2,
                                   comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                                   author:"25 Cent",
                                   date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               }                                                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          name:'Vadonut',
                           image: 'images/vadonut.png',
                          category: 'appetizer',
                           label:'New',
                          price:'1.99',
                          description:'A quintessential ConFusion experience, is it a vada or is it a donut?',
                           comments: [
                               {
                                   rating:5,
                                   comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                                   author:"John Lemon",
                                   date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                                   author:"Paul McVites",
                                   date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:3,
                                   comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                                   author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                                   date:"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                                   author:"Ringo Starry",
                                   date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:2,
                                   comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                                   author:"25 Cent",
                                   date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               }
                                                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          name:'ElaiCheese Cake',
                           image: 'images/elaicheesecake.png',
                          category: 'dessert',
                           label:'',
                          price:'2.99',
                          description:'A delectable, semi-sweet New York Style Cheese Cake, with Graham cracker crust and spiced with Indian cardamoms',
                           comments: [
                               {
                                   rating:5,
                                   comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                                   author:"John Lemon",
                                   date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                                   author:"Paul McVites",
                                   date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:3,
                                   comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                                   author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                                   date:"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                                   author:"Ringo Starry",
                                   date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:2,
                                   comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                                   author:"25 Cent",
                                   date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               }                                                          ]
                        }
                        ];
         var menufac = {};
        menufac.getDishes = function(){
                                        return dishes;
                                    };
                    menufac.getDish = function (index) {
                                        return dishes[index];
                };
                return menufac;
    }
);
```

here's my order of arrangement

```
<script src="../app/scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="../app/scripts/controller.js"></script>
<script src="../app/scripts/service.js"></script>
```

I know its not tough at all but I am not able to figure out

Comment: can you show the order that the scripts are listed in your HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a superfluous brace on the third line which probably will lead to a compile error. Maybe it is your bug. If not please edit your question.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('confusionApp'){
    .factory('menuFactory',function(){
...
```

Comment: What a fool I am. Thanks